# JSON response not parsed

Tags: jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I'm developing an app in Sencha Touch 2.0 that is supposed to parse JSON through a web service that resides on a different domain.

I'm stuck parsing JSON. If I use nodes with names like `title`, `author description link` etc then it works perfectly.

But if I use other names for nodes then it does not display anything.

Here is the JSON response I'm trying to parse:

http://stassuet.byethost15.com/services/test/index.php

This is what I'm doing to parse the response in Sencha app:

```
Ext.define('GS.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'GS.model.MainEvent',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'
        //'GS.util.JsonpX'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'GS.model.MainEvent',
        storeId: '55',

        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/xml"
            //"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
            //"Origin": "goodnews.pk",
            //"Referer": "goodnews.pk"
        },

        method: 'GET',
        callbackKey: 'myFunction',

        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://stassuet.byethost15.com/services/test/index.php',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'albums.images'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of configurations set even though you don't need them. For example:

- headers
- method
- callbackKey

Is there a reason for this?

Anyway, using this class, everything loads as it should:

```
Ext.define('Example.store.SO', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [
            'name',
            'author',
            'last_modified'
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://stassuet.byethost15.com/services/test/index.php',
            reader: {
                rootProperty: 'albums.images'
            }
        }
    }
});
```